# Getting Error : Symbol extraction process failed in Organizer

Tags: iphone, objective-c, cocoa-touch, xcode, ios4

I am getting following error while I am connecting my iPhone to organizer.

[image]

I perform following steps to avoid collecting data every time I connect my device to Mac.

To do this, simply go to the /Developer/Platforms/iPhoneOS.platform/DeviceSupport folder and manually copy the Symbols subfolder and/or the DeveloperDiskImage.* files from 4.2 (8C134) to 4.2.1 (8C148) (or whatever release folder Organizer creates for your device).

What can be done?

Comment: Have you tried to restart your device and xcode,clean the build targets,and remove the app from the device.And then run again.Might it help you but i am not sure.Better to try it as it won't cost you

Comment: I'm also getting the "Symbol extraction process failed" message. Have an old 3G, installed iOS 4.2.1, and can't use it for development! Please help!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I had the same problem, but what worked for me, was to go to `/Developer/Platforms/iPhoneOS.platform/DeviceSupport` and just delete the 4.2.1 (8C148) files, by typing

```
sudo rm -fr "4.2.1 (8C148)".
```

After that I plugged in my iPhone again, and it fetched the debug symbols just fine.